# How to redirect response to a file

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, io

I am trying to save the response as HTML to a file, but there is no method available on `HttpServletResponse response` to retrieve HTML.

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.View review = this.vr.resolveViewName("report2", Locale.US);

        review.render(model.asMap(), request, response);

        System.out.println("html"+response.getOutputStream());
```

I am using **spring-web-mvc**. I extracted the above code from a controller.

How can I write the HTML content to file?

**UPDATE**

```
public class PDFServletResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private StringWriter  output;

    public PDFServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        //output= new CharArrayWriter();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

     public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          }

          public String toString() {
            return output.toString();
          }
}

 org.springframework.web.servlet.View review = this.vr.resolveViewName("report2", Locale.US);
       // System.out.println("rendered html : " + response.getContentAsString());
   //   reView.render();
        review.render(model.asMap(), request, response);

        PDFServletResponse responseWrapper = new PDFServletResponse((HttpServletResponse) response);
        //  chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
```

Here, how do I handle filter?

Comment: How about using an HttpServletResponseWrapper and overriding the getOutputStream() / getWriter() methods to return a FileOutputStream or FileWriter that writes to the file?

Comment: thanks for the hint. I will give a try and will update the post.

Comment: You can also just change where System.out is pointing

Comment: In HttpServletResponseWrapper class I don't see getOutputStream()/getWriter() methods to overwrite. Have I missed anything here?

Comment: getOutputStream() and getWriter()  are inherited from the superclass javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper

Comment: Create a FileOutputStream and write to it?